# could not add the result of two class in the ExtentReport

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when i run first class the result is added to the report but when i run the second class the report don't keep the result of the first class

// SimpleReportFactory {

```
package Rapport;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.DisplayOrder;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;

public class SimpleReportFactory {

private static ExtentReports reporter;

public static synchronized ExtentReports getReporter() {
    if (reporter == null) {
        reporter = new ExtentReports("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/SimpleReport3.html", true, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);
    }
    return reporter;
}

public static synchronized void closeReporter() {
    reporter.flush();
    reporter.close();
}
}
```

//First class Test001

```
package Rapport;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Test001 {

private ExtentReports reporter =  SimpleReportFactory.getReporter();



@Test
public void simpleTest002()
{
    ExtentTest testReporter = reporter.startTest("simpleTest002", "This is a simple simpleTest002");
    testReporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting test simpleTest002");
    int a = 100;
    int b = 30;

    testReporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Loading the value of a to " + a);
    testReporter.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Loading the value of b to " + b);
    reporter.endTest(testReporter);

}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite()
{
    reporter.close();
}
}
```

// second class Test002

```
package Rapport;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Test002 {

private ExtentReports reporter =  SimpleReportFactory.getReporter();


@Test
public void simpleTest004()
{
    ExtentTest testReporter = reporter.startTest("simpleTest004", "This is a simple simpleTest004");
    testReporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting test simpleTest004");
    int a = 100;
    int b = 30;

    testReporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Loading the value of a to " + a);
    testReporter.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Loading the value of b to " + b);
    reporter.endTest(testReporter);

}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite()
{
    reporter.close();
}
```

Comment: How will it retain the results of the previous run? You are creating a new instance every time!

Comment: you are not supposed to depend on the order of execution of the test cases

Comment: how can i add the result without creating a new instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using  the

```
private ExtentReports reporter =  SimpleReportFactory.getReporter();
```

twice;

For Extent report, if u use the ExtentReport instance twice, than the details of first instace is cleared, it shows only the last, in ur case it shows you only the second instance result.

So, try to initiate Extent Report only one time and than use this instance to the whole test cycle.

Make

```
ExtentReports reporter
```

instance Global and static and than use this

```
reporter instance to the whole test cycle.
```

close the reporter instance at the last of test execution.

Comment: I have change true by false  and it works reporter = new ExtentReports("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/SimpleReport3.html", true, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);

Comment: That is not a good approach. Better to use Singleton pattern as described by noor

Comment: 1.create a class where extent report is initialized
2.Than in the main class, get the initialized extent reporter.