# Extent Reports - All the results are not getting captured when I have 2 or more class files

Tags: java, selenium, report, testng, extent

I am having trouble pushing my complete test results into extent reports - using 2.4 release version. Basically I am having 2 tests 1 test in each class file and have a "SimpleReportFactory" as my base reporter.

when I run the tests via testng.xml only the last test is getting captured, please help in resolving this issue, I have checked other posts, I am finding few answers, but failing in applying it. I need a working example where I can use an extent report instance and use it across tests and generate 1 report for all the tests.

I am getting null pointer exception on my 2nd test class, when I run the below tests via testng xml, its a framework based tests! Here is one of the posts I found([could not add the result of two class in the ExtentReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180844/could-not-add-the-result-of-two-class-in-the-extentreport/36181892#36181892)) where I tried to implement the suggestion given, but its giving me NPE! Not sure how to implement an instance and use it globally.

```
    public class SimpleReportFactory {

    public static ExtentReports reporter;

    public static synchronized ExtentReports getReporter () {
        if (reporter == null) {
            reporter = new ExtentReports("SimpleReport.html", true, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);
        }
        return reporter;
    }

    public static synchronized void closeReporter() {
        reporter.flush();
        reporter.close();
    }

}

    public class Registration extends BaseClass {


    public ExtentReports reporter = SimpleReportFactory.getReporter();


    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        intialize();


    }


    @Test
    public void TestUserRegistration() throws Exception {

        ExtentTest testreporter = reporter.startTest("TestUserRegistration");


        WebElement ProfileLink = getWebElement("profilepage.createaccount.profilelink");
        ProfileLink.click();
        testreporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, " Click on the Profile Link from HomePage");


        RandomEmail();
        driverwait(1);
        WebElement Password = getWebElement("profilepage.createaccount.password");
        Password.sendKeys(Repository.getProperty("password"));
        driverwait(1);
        WebElement SubmitButton = getWebElement("profilepage.createaccount.submitbutton");
        SubmitButton.click();
        reporter.endTest(testreporter);


    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void testDown() {
        CloseBrowser();
        reporter.close();


   }

}

    public class SignIn extends BaseClass {

    ExtentReports reporter;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        intialize();

    }

    @Test
    public void LoginToTheApplication() throws Exception {

        ExtentTest testreporter = reporter.startTest("LoginToTheApplication");

        WebElement profilelink = getWebElement("profilepage.signin.profilelink");
        profilelink.click();
        testreporter.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Hey");

        WebElement signinemail = getWebElement("profilepage.signin.emailaddress");
        signinemail.sendKeys(Repository.getProperty("signinemailaddress"));

        driverwait(1);

        WebElement signinpassword = getWebElement("profilepage.signin.password");
        signinpassword.sendKeys(Repository.getProperty("signinpassword"));

        driverwait(1);

        WebElement clicksubmit = getWebElement("profilepage.signin.submitbutton");
        clicksubmit.click();
        reporter.endTest(testreporter);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void testDown() {

    CloseBrowser();
    reporter.close();
}
```

Comment: Please try (null==reporter) in place of (reporter == null)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your reporter as ovrriding mode not appending mode. Change the initialization like this

```
reporter = new ExtentReports("SimpleReport.html", false, DisplayOrder.NEWEST_FIRST);
```

This will keep your previously written data and new tests will be appended to the existing report.

**Edited Answer for edited question**

You are not initializing your ExtentReports just declared it in your new class. Initialize it just like you did it in the class **Registration**.

Use

```
public ExtentReports reporter = SimpleReportFactory.getReporter();
```

in your **SignIn** clas instead of

```
ExtentReports reporter;
```

only.

Comment: Hello optimist_creeper,

Sorry, My Question was not perfect, I got confused with another project that was there in my IDE, I have modified my question above, please take a look and let me know if u have any feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! But still this doesn't answer my question, please check the similar question asked in another thread that I have linked above, please see the suggestion given by noor, I am having trouble implementing it. I dont know how to initialize the extent report once and use that initialized extent report object or method to all my other classes.